# C Program is stuck, doesnt enter main()

Tags: c, multithreading, program-entry-point, no-response

I am trying to run a program where one thread takes data from standart input and than and the other gives it on a standart output, nothing too complicated, but when I run my program with */.filename < test.in > test.out* it doesnt do anything. When I compliled it by using *gcc -pthread filename.c -o filename -W -Wall*, no errors or warnings seems to accour. Can someone explain? Also in file test.out nothing is displayed and in test.in is a simple sentence. 
This is the program

```
#define V  300

pthread_cond_t cond;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
char a[300];
int p = 0;
int w = 0;


void *thread1() {

    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("thread1");
        while(p >0){
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        }

        p = fread(a, sizeof(char), V ,stdin);

        if(p == 0){
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        if(p <= V){ 
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

}

void *thread2() {
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("thread2");

        while(w >0){
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        }

        w = fwrite(a, sizeof(char),p, stdout);

        if(w == 0){
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        if(w <= V ){ 
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

int main (void) {
    printf("main/n");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_t t1, t2; 

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init (&cond, NULL);

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, vlakno1,  NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, vlakno2,  NULL);


    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("main/n");`...did you mean `printf("main\n");`?

Comment: Je suis désolé, mais je ne comprends pas votre langue.

Comment: my bad, but it still doesnt write down anything and is stuck

Comment: There are deadlocks. Your condition variable logic is broken. The *reader* thread should wake up when *there's free space in the buffer*, and signal when *there's data in the buffer*. The *writer* thread should wake up when *there's data in the buffer*, and signal when *there's free space in the buffer*, The reader thread should fill up the free space. The writer thread should free up the filled space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the obvious typo in your `printf("main/n");` rather than `printf("main\n");` (or just `puts("main");`) but this is a detail and not thre reason why your program will never finish

in *vlakno1* you create a deadlock doing :

```
    if(poc_precitanych == 0){
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

because you do not unlock the mutext, must be

```
    if(poc_precitanych == 0){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

you have the same problem in *vlakno2* :

```
    if(pocet_pisanych == 0){
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

must be

```
    if(pocet_pisanych == 0){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

The following is also strange :

```
    pocet_pisanych = fwrite(a, sizeof(char),poc_precitanych, stdout);

    if(pocet_pisanych == 0){
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

even it is not impossible, it is difficult to have a write on *stdou* without success. So the alone chance for you to go out that loop is to have `poc_precitanych` valuing 0

Additional remark, you `#define V  300` but you do `char a[300];` while you use *V* elsewhere. Better to do `char a[V];` or to use `sizeof(a)` elsewhere without defining V

---

Examples of execution after the changes :

```
/tmp % ./a.out < /dev/null
main
vlakno 1vlakno 2
```

there is nothing to read so `poc_precitanych` values 0 and the two thread finishes, but

```
/tmp % echo "1 2 3" | ./a.out
main
vlakno 1vlakno 1vlakno 21 2 3
^C
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to correct it, it does write to the test.out now so I susspected there would be something wrong in threads

Comment: @ZuzanaKlinovska yes you have problem, I have lot of doubt with the threads waiting each other through ` pthread_cond_wait`, doing that is an easy way to have a deadlock too. Note also doing that each thread waits for the other one so finally there is no useful multi threading, but probably this is just an exercise

Comment: It is an exercise, we learn how to deal with threads :) everything is kind of new to me, I marked your answer and thanks again :)

Comment: @ZuzanaKlinovska you welcome, have nice programming :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not see anything on the terminal because of the typo in `printf("main/n");`

`printf`'s output is not flushed to `stdout` and the threads created consume loop for ever, or at least for a long time.

You should add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` statement to verify this.

Then you can try `printf("main\n");` without the `fflush()` to verify that `stdout` is line buffered, ie: output is flushed to the terminal when a newline is output.

If you redirect output to a file, `stdout` is usually fully buffered, hence you should add an explicit `fflush(stdout);` after each output operation so you can see the output in the output file on the fly or after killing the program.

Note that the code would be easier to read for most users here if you use English words for the identifiers, types, comments and messages.

Comment: Thank you, although now it is stuck somewhere in Threads, but I ll have to deal with it, I tried to change the code as well ;)